# Remove specific string from a complex column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df

```py
data = {'A': ['1','2','3'],
        'B': ['[rududj,person sueuf, sadioa} ','kskldperson23, sdoap03]','| sdaasd, isdaoidi]']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to remove the rows contain with `person`

The output should be

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | sdaasd, isdaoidi] |

my python code `df = df[~df.B.str.contains('person', na=False)]`
does not remove any rows somehow.

Comment: So you test your data from question `data = {'A': ['1','2','3'], 'B': ['[rududj,person sueuf, sadioa} ','kskldperson23, sdoap03]','| sdaasd, isdaoidi]']} df = pd.DataFrame(data)` and failed?

Comment: because for me working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is there are lists, so use first [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df = df[~df.B.str.join(' ').str.contains('person', na=False)]
```

Comment: there is space after person will this still work? @jezrael

Comment: @sdu27322 - I think yes, if not working need to see `print (df.B.head().tolist())`

Comment: still not remove any rows

Comment: ['[rududj,person sueuf, sadioa} ', 'kskldperson23, sdoap03]', '| sdaasd, isdaoidi]'] @jezrael

Comment: @sdu27322 - It is weird, because your solution working nice for me.